# Use Reachability.m in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, reachability

I am trying to use the Reachability function in my application. Now I get several errors in the Reachability.m file. I think it's due to the new Xcode version (does not allow [release]).

Does anyone have experience in this case?

Comment: There is no need to edit your question title to put SOLVED on there, we can see there is an accepted answer in the list of questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reachability is not ARC compliant. You can disable ARC on a per file basis.

Select your project -> target -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources ->  Double click the Reachability.m -> add -fno-objc-arc.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a [modified Reachability](https://gist.github.com/1182373) that's meant to be ARC-compliant.